# Check-out XTools Pro with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, extensions, error-000824, xtools-pro

I have an arcpy script that uses a XTools Pro geoprocessing tool, which works if I run it from ArcMap (with the XTools Pro extension enabled), but if I run it outside of ArcMap I get an error.

Tool I'm running:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/DataEast/XTools Pro/Toolbox/XTools Pro.tbx")
arcpy.XToolsGP_DispersePoints_xtp(InputLayer, OutputLayer, "0.25 Meters", "1 Meters", "BY_CLUSTERS", "RING", "", "")
```

Error message:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError was unhandled by user code
Message: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
Failed to execute (XToolsGP_DispersePoints).
```

I have attempted to enabled this extension from arcpy with no success, and have found the XTools Pro help pages don't mention arcpy at all (so now I wonder if it's even supported).

How can I enable the XTools Pro extension from within arcpy?  I've attempted to use the following, but am unsure what arcpy would call the XTools Pro extension, so may be using the incorrect Extension name.  (I have tried `XTools`, `XToolsPro`, `XTools-Pro`, `XTools Pro`, `xtp`, `XToolsGP`)

```
if arcpy.CheckExtension("XToolsPro") == "Available":
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("XToolsPro")
else:
    print "XTools Pro Not Available"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XTools Pro** geoprocessing tools require 32bit python, and won't work if using the 64bit background geoprocessing.  Switching to 32bit worked.

It seems that when using 64bit python XTools Pro reports `The Tool is not Licensed` however this is misleading in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the XTools Pro toolbox using the `arcpy.ImportToolbox()` function. The toolbox is usually located in the  *C:\Program Files (x86)\DataEast\XTools Pro\Toolbox* folder; assuming this is the case, add the following statement at the top of your code (after importing arcpy):

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox('C:\Program Files (x86)\DataEast\XTools Pro\Toolbox\XTools Pro.tbx')
```

If you're just using the Python window in ArcMap, just type the above into the interpreter and the toolbox will be imported.

Once the toolbox is imported, its tools are accessed using the syntax `arcpy.xtp.toolname`

[image]

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that line in my question - I already had the toolbox imported: `arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/DataEast/XTools Pro/Toolbox/XTools Pro.tbx")`

Comment: your code should reference the module name "xtp" so you would use `arcpy.xtp.XToolsGP_DispersePoints(InputLayer, OutputLayer, "0.25 Meters", "1 Meters", "BY_CLUSTERS", "RING", "", "")`

Comment: I've made that change `arcpy.XToolsGP_DispersePoints_xtp` to `arcpy.xtp.XToolsGP_DispersePoints` but still get the same error.  Both of those work in ArcMap directly, just not from standalone python script.

Comment: wow. you've got me then!

Comment: I just ran a test with the Disperse Points tool with no problem. Have you tried just removing the check for extension availability? Also, Disperse Points is a paid tool, so have you got a valid licence?

Comment: Good suggestions - yes I only added the check for extension when it started failing.  And yes have a valid license.  As I say the script works fine from within ArcMap.  (No layers are referenced from within ArcMap - I can run it from an empty ArcMap and it works no problem).  And the rest of the script runs fine, it just fails on this step.

Comment: Try substituting the parameter variables passed to the `arcpy.xtp.XToolsGP_DispersePoints` function with literal values.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and suggestions @adam.  My script was correct all along, however it turns out that XTools won't work with 64bit python.  I was trying to rule it out so I switched python to 32bit and it all worked flawlessly!  Much appreciated.

Comment: wow that's pretty surprising really. glad you got it sorted!